# RegEx to exclude some users from Bugzilla Group

Tags: regex, regex-negation, bugzilla

my team uses Bugzilla for bug tracking and we use the group function with RegExes to grant or deny access to certain products.
What I am currently trying to achieve is that all users that carry our domain in their user name (e.g. "peter@mycompany.com") should be allowed to access product X. But I want to exclude all colleagues, that also carry the word "partner" before the domain (e.g. "clark-partner@mycompany.com").

I tried to achieve that by using negative look behind:

```
(?<!partner)@mycompany.com$
```

The problem: Users that are included in the group are kicked out after they log into Bugzilla again. I am afraid that the RegEx engine does not fully support look behind/forward. How would you implement this without look arounds?

Thanks in advance!
dbug0685

Comment: Bugzilla is written in Perl which has pretty much one of the most powerful regex engines around. I think it might even be one of the first engines to implement look behind/ahead assertions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this regex instead: [`^.*?(?<!partner)@mycompany\.com$`](https://regex101.com/r/MiynpY/1). Emails with `partner` won't get matched at all while others will. I don't know if the regex you shared was the whole thing, if so you are certainly missing `.*` before the lookbehind. Also the period in .com should be escaped, or it will match any character.